# How to run multiple functions which have to wait for Hardware?

Tags: python

Hi I got a program which reads multiple sensors, records and graphs the data. And can start procedures according to the sensor values. My problem is that the procedures need to wait for the physical hardware to perform their operation.
Lets say I got 2 analog sensors. if the analog value of s1 is below X Precedure P1 is started which takes 30 seconds. if analog value of s2 is below Y Procedure P2 is started which takes also 30 seconds.
So by using sleep(30) I am blocking the rest of the program. So my sulution was to use sleep(1) and record the data. The problem arises if P1 is still running and s2 falls below Y in that case I got no good solution.
would something like asyncronous multiprocessing work. So running the two processes in new threads or something similar. And if so how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem :

```py
import logging
import time


_values_for_sensor_a = iter([0, 0, 456, 0, 0])
_values_for_sensor_b = iter([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])


def read_sensor_a() -> int:
    return next(_values_for_sensor_a)  # example !


def read_sensor_b() -> int:
    return next(_values_for_sensor_b)  # example !


def procedure_p1() -> None:
    logging.info("beginning procedure P1")
    time.sleep(5)  # shorter than your 30 seconds
    logging.info("ending procedure P1")


def procedure_p2() -> None:
    logging.info("beginning procedure P2")
    time.sleep(5)  # shorter than your 30 seconds
    logging.info("ending procedure P2")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # setup
    logger = logging.getLogger(None)
    log_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    log_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(message)s"))
    logger.addHandler(log_handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # operating ...
    while True:
        measure_a = read_sensor_a()
        logging.info(f"{measure_a=:.0f}")
        measure_b = read_sensor_b()
        logging.info(f"{measure_b=:.0f}")

        if measure_a > 100:
            # quick, initiate procedure P1 !
            procedure_p1()
        elif measure_b > 100:
            procedure_p2()

        logger.info("short pause")
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

```
2022-02-01 16:19:00,932 measure_a=0
2022-02-01 16:19:00,932 measure_b=0
2022-02-01 16:19:00,932 short pause

2022-02-01 16:19:01,933 measure_a=0
2022-02-01 16:19:01,933 measure_b=0
2022-02-01 16:19:01,933 short pause

2022-02-01 16:19:02,934 measure_a=456
2022-02-01 16:19:02,934 measure_b=0
2022-02-01 16:19:02,934 /!\ beginning procedure P1
2022-02-01 16:19:07,936 /!\ ending procedure P1
2022-02-01 16:19:07,936 short pause

2022-02-01 16:19:08,938 measure_a=0
2022-02-01 16:19:08,938 measure_b=0
2022-02-01 16:19:08,938 short pause

2022-02-01 16:19:09,939 measure_a=0
2022-02-01 16:19:09,939 measure_b=0
2022-02-01 16:19:09,939 short pause
```

Indeed, there was a 5-seconds pause in the sensor reading because the **thread** running your Python code was busy (in this example it was busy sleeping).

The solution is to have multiple threads, so that the one reading the values is never busy doing something else.

```py
import itertools
import logging
import time
import threading


_values_for_sensor_a = iter(itertools.chain([0, 0, 456], itertools.repeat(0)))  # 0, 0, 456, then always 0
_values_for_sensor_b = iter(itertools.chain([0, 0, 0, 0, 789], itertools.repeat(0)))  # 0, 0, 0, 0, 789 then always 0


def read_sensor_a() -> int:
    return next(_values_for_sensor_a)  # example !


def read_sensor_b() -> int:
    return next(_values_for_sensor_b)  # example !


def procedure_p1() -> None:
    logging.info("/!\ beginning procedure P1")
    time.sleep(5)  # shorter than your 30 seconds
    logging.info("/!\ ending procedure P1")


def procedure_p2() -> None:
    logging.info("/!\ beginning procedure P2")
    time.sleep(5)  # shorter than your 30 seconds
    logging.info("/!\ ending procedure P2")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # setup
    logger = logging.getLogger(None)
    log_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    log_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s %(threadName)s %(message)s"))  # <-- added `threadName`
    logger.addHandler(log_handler)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    threads_running = []

    # operating ...
    while True:
        measure_a = read_sensor_a()
        logging.info(f"{measure_a=:.0f}")
        measure_b = read_sensor_b()
        logging.info(f"{measure_b=:.0f}")

        if measure_a > 100:
            thread = threading.Thread(target=procedure_p1, args=[])
            thread.start()
            threads_running.append(thread)
        elif measure_b > 100:
            thread = threading.Thread(target=procedure_p2, args=[])
            thread.start()
            threads_running.append(thread)

        # check if one procedure has finished
        for thread in threads_running:
            thread.join(timeout=0)  # non-blocking because timeout=0
            if thread.is_alive():
                # the join has timeout, so the thread is still running
                pass
            else:
                threads_running.remove(thread)
                logging.info(f"removing thread {thread.name}")

        logger.info("short pause\n")
        time.sleep(1)
```

```
2022-02-01 16:30:06,145 MainThread measure_a=0
2022-02-01 16:30:06,145 MainThread measure_b=0
2022-02-01 16:30:06,145 MainThread short pause

2022-02-01 16:30:07,145 MainThread measure_a=0
2022-02-01 16:30:07,145 MainThread measure_b=0
2022-02-01 16:30:07,146 MainThread short pause

2022-02-01 16:30:08,147 MainThread measure_a=456
2022-02-01 16:30:08,147 MainThread measure_b=0
2022-02-01 16:30:08,147 Thread-1 /!\ beginning procedure P1
2022-02-01 16:30:08,147 MainThread short pause

2022-02-01 16:30:09,148 MainThread measure_a=0
2022-02-01 16:30:09,148 MainThread measure_b=0
2022-02-01 16:30:09,148 MainThread short pause

2022-02-01 16:30:10,149 MainThread measure_a=0
2022-02-01 16:30:10,150 MainThread measure_b=456
2022-02-01 16:30:10,150 Thread-2 /!\ beginning procedure P2
2022-02-01 16:30:10,150 MainThread short pause

2022-02-01 16:30:11,151 MainThread measure_a=0
2022-02-01 16:30:11,151 MainThread measure_b=0
2022-02-01 16:30:11,151 MainThread short pause

2022-02-01 16:30:12,152 MainThread measure_a=0
2022-02-01 16:30:12,152 MainThread measure_b=0
2022-02-01 16:30:12,152 MainThread short pause

2022-02-01 16:30:13,152 Thread-1 /!\ ending procedure P1
2022-02-01 16:30:13,153 MainThread measure_a=0
2022-02-01 16:30:13,154 MainThread measure_b=0
2022-02-01 16:30:13,154 MainThread removing thread Thread-1
2022-02-01 16:30:13,154 MainThread short pause

2022-02-01 16:30:14,155 MainThread measure_a=0
2022-02-01 16:30:14,155 MainThread measure_b=0
2022-02-01 16:30:14,155 MainThread short pause

2022-02-01 16:30:15,155 Thread-2 /!\ ending procedure P2
2022-02-01 16:30:15,156 MainThread measure_a=0
2022-02-01 16:30:15,156 MainThread measure_b=0
2022-02-01 16:30:15,156 MainThread removing thread Thread-2
2022-02-01 16:30:15,156 MainThread short pause

2022-02-01 16:30:16,157 MainThread measure_a=0
2022-02-01 16:30:16,158 MainThread measure_b=0
2022-02-01 16:30:16,158 MainThread short pause

2022-02-01 16:30:17,159 MainThread measure_a=0
2022-02-01 16:30:17,159 MainThread measure_b=0
2022-02-01 16:30:17,159 MainThread short pause

2022-02-01 16:30:18,160 MainThread measure_a=0
2022-02-01 16:30:18,160 MainThread measure_b=0
2022-02-01 16:30:18,160 MainThread short pause
```

Now, the procedures are not blocking the reading of values.

This is simple threading, no need for fancy "async multiprocessing".

Comment: @Chris it's not my question, this is just an answer to both "do I need async multiprocessing" and "how to do it".